# A function that moves a tile in the game of fifteen

Tags: c, sliding-tile-puzzle

I've created a a function that will move a tile that a user specifies within the game board.

The game board can be from 3*3 up to 9*9 and is filled with values 1 to d - 1.
This function is called within another function that keeps track of "space" array and the 2d "board"array.

This function works however, I feel that I might be using too many constants? How can I make this better?

```
/**
* If tile borders empty space, moves tile and returns true, else
* returns false. 
* 
* @param   int     tile    The tile the user wants to move
* @param   int[]   space   Space keeps track of where the space is on the board
* @return  bool    
*/
bool move(int tile, int space[])
{
  //check the tile to the left of the space tile so we can swap the space tile with the tile the user wanted
  if ( board[ space[0] ][ space[1] + 1 ] == tile ) {

    board[ space[0] ][ space[1] + 1 ] = 0;

    board[ space[0] ][ space[1] ] = tile;
    space[1]++;

    return true;

  //check the tile to the right of the space tile so we can swap the space tile with the tile the user selected
  }else if ( board[ space[0] ][ space[1] - 1] == tile ) {

    board[ space[0] ][ space[1] - 1 ] = 0;

    board[ space[0] ][space[1] ] = tile;
    space[1]--;

    return true;

  //check the tile to the top of the space tile so we can swap the space tile with the tile the user selected
  }else if ( board[ space[0] + 1 ][ space[1] ] == tile ) {

    board[ space[0] + 1 ][ space[1] ] = 0;

    board[ space[0] ][space[1] ] = tile;
    space[0]++;

    return true;

  //check the tile to the bottom of the space tile so we can swap the space tile with the tile the user selected
  }else if ( board[ space[0] - 1 ][ space[1] ] == tile ) {

    board[ space[0] - 1 ][ space[1] ] = 0;

    board[ space[0] ][space[1] ] = tile;
    space[0]--;

    return true;

  } else {
    //the tile does not border the space tile
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `board`?  How do you know you aren't reading past the array bounds of `board` when you do something like `board[space[0]+1][space[1]]`?

Comment: @JS1 Board will be a two dimensional array from 3x3 to 9x9 (d*d) filed with tiles 1 to d - 1.  The function isn't concerned wether its reading past the array bounds as it only cares if you can find the tile. Unless I should be concerned with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](/a/76949/9357), storing the board as a one-dimensional array would make the logic much simpler.  For one thing, the location of the space could be represented as a single `int` rather than as a two-element array — and arrays are a pain to work with in C.

For an \$n \times n\$ board, the location would be represented as \$n \times row + col\$.  To get the neighbours of `space`, you would only need to check…

- `space - n` (above) and `space + n` (below)

  Index \$i\$ would be in bounds if \$0 \le i < n^2\$.
- `space - 1` (left), `space + 1` (right)

  Index \$space \pm 1\$ would be in bounds if it is in the same row, i.e.  \$\lfloor \frac{space \pm 1}{n} \rfloor\$ = \$\lfloor \frac{space}{n} \rfloor\$.

Comment: This is great! so instead of a 2d array we can just use 1d array that is the length of n * n?

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

#### Reading past array bounds

Each of your four checks has the possibility of reading past array bounds.  Very bad things can happen when that happens.  I will illustrate with an example:

Let `board` be defined as `int board[3][3]`, and let`tile = 1, space[0] = 2, space[1] = 2`.  When the code reaches this first check:

> ```
>   if ( board[ space[0] ][ space[1] + 1 ] == tile ) {
>
>     board[ space[0] ][ space[1] + 1 ] = 0;
>
>     board[ space[0] ][ space[1] ] = tile;
>     space[1]++;
>
>     return true;
>   }
> ```

It will read the value of `board[2][3]`, which is past the end of the `board` array.  The memory location corresponding to `board[2][3]` is 4 bytes past the end of `board`, and will probably be occupied by some other global variable in your program.  Suppose this memory location contains the value `1`.  In this case, you will swap the `1` with the `0` in `board[2][2]`, and then you will set `space[1]` to `3` which is outside of your board dimensions.  So now:

1. Whatever global variable held the value `1` will now have the value `0` for no reason.
2. The next time you call into this function, you will be reading even further out of bounds because `space[1]` is 3, which will cause you to read from `board[2][4]`.

#### Simplify with loop

Instead of writing each of your four direction checks separately, you can combine them into a single loop.  Here is how I would do that (with additional bounds checking as well to fix the first problem):

```
bool move(int tile, int space[])
{
    int dx[4] = {  0,  0,  1, -1 };
    int dy[4] = {  1, -1,  0,  0 };

    // Check in each of the four directions.
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int x = space[0] + dx[i];
        int y = space[1] + dy[i];

        // If out of bounds, skip this direction.
        if (x < 0 || x >= BOARD_SIZE || y < 0 || y >= BOARD_SIZE)
            continue;

        // If we find the tile, swap them with the empty space.
        if (board[x][y] == tile) {
            board[x][y] = 0;
            board[space[0]][space[1]] = tile;
            space[0] = x;
            space[1] = y;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was hoping I would be able to use a loop and this is a pretty neat way to implement it. What is your opinion on storing the board as a flattened array vs a 2d array?

Comment: @JosephPalomino I think that both flattened and 2D have advantages and disadvantages.  In actuality, your 2D array is just a flat array in memory anyways.  The only difference is that you index a 2D array with `[row][column]` and a flat array with `[row*NUM_COLS + column]`.  Even with a 2D array, you could still store your `space` variable as an `int` and convert it to a row/column pair when you needed to.